# Set child elements width depending on content to fill 100% width

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have navigation with 9 items,and I need to make each navigation item to have width of theyr **content + padding** so that they can fill full width of parent. And also it need to be responsive to certain width. How could this be achived?

[image]

Comment: What result are you expecting? When the window is made narrower, do you want the padding or text size to decrease, or do you want the navigation items to start a second row?

Comment: Add width those `nav` as auto, it will fill-up things automatically.

Comment: @Run_Script on resize decrease padding, and when width reaches 900px it will switch to mobile version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility – just change the `flex-grow` number for each `div` to the number of letters in the corresponding `nav` element.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav div {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {flex-grow: 4;}
#div2 {flex-grow: 3;}
#div3 {flex-grow: 11;}
#div4 {flex-grow: 10;}
#div5 {flex-grow: 6;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="div1">Here</div>
  <div id="div2">Are</div>
  <div id="div3">Some Random</div>
  <div id="div4">Navigation</div>
  <div id="div5">Titles</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best would be using `display:flex` and `flex-basis`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` properties where needed.

Learn more about Flexbox Layout Module in CSS here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Additional tutorial here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/